# Controlling Time in the House of Representatives

Tags: united-states, parliament

During the sessions of the US House of Representatives, I noticed that a time holder can either:

- yield themselves as much time as they may consume to speak. (up to the limit defined)
- yield a supporter of their stance a specific amount of time or as much as they may consume (up to the limit defined)
- yield back (surrender) the balance of their time to the chair (aka forfeit their time of debate)
- Reserve the balance of their time to use later.

In the House of Representatives, can a holder of debate time continuously reserve the balance of their time when called on?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're asking here, although it sounds like an interesting question.  Are you asking whether they can use the "Reserve balance" option as many times as they want?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking. I often see one member hold their time and continually reserve until they're ready to close but wondered how often can they reserve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### By the rules: Yes

I'm not in the habit of watching the House's activities, but according to their [rules](http://clerk.house.gov/legislative/house-rules.pdf):

> Except  as  provided  in  paragraph   (a),  a  Member,  Delegate,  or 
>   Resident   Commissioner   may   not   speak   more    than  once  to 
>   the  same  question  with- out leave of the House.

(Rule XVII, 3b).

"Speak more than once" is a bit deceiving. It refers to the Representative being recognized to speak. The general flow of this process is contained in Rule XVII 2.  When the speaker is recognized they are allotted 1 hour or less. This 1 hour can be broken up into multiple segments.

There is no reason to think that a person couldn't (for whatever reason) continually reserve their time.

### More Practically

Rules aside, why would they? Legislatures are extremely time-crunched. Once it becomes clear that there is no strategic value to holding on to that time, generally they will yield.

Again, the rules are not laws, but internal rules which the House or Speaker can suspend at times.  If the Speaker felt like the rules were being abused, there are measures that can be taken to work around the offending Representative.